# Defining a function with summation

Tags: python

I need to plot a surface of [steady-state velocity profile in rectangular channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbQcX.jpg). I tried to do it like this:

```
a = 4*w**2/(pi**3*nu)*(-dp)
def cosh (j,z):
    return np.cosh(j*pi*z/w)
def U(y,z):
    for j in range (1,21,2):
        return a*np.sum(((-1)**(0.5*(j-1)))*(1-cosh(j,z)/cosh(j,h/2))*np.cos(j*pi*y/w)/j**3)
y = np.linspace(0,h,25)
z = np.linspace(0,w,25)
print(U(y,z))
```

But the last command returns a float, not a 2D-array. Can anyone give some advice about what is wrong with this code?

UPD:

Thanks for replies, i get it that shouldn't have write a return statement inside for loop. But replacing it array is not what i need, since function U should return a single float. I replaced it with ordinary summation:

```
i = np.linspace(1,25,13)
a = 4*w**2/(pi**3*nu)*(-dp)
def cosh (j,z):
    return np.cosh(j*pi*z/w)
def U(y,z):
    return a*np.sum(((-1)**(0.5*(i-1)))*(1-cosh(i,z)/cosh(i,h/2))*np.cos(i*pi*y/w)/i**3)
y = np.linspace(0,h,25)
z = np.linspace(0,w,25)
print(U(y,z))
```

But it gave me another error:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (13,) (25,)

It seems like U produces an array, not a float. But np.sum() returns a sum of all elements, which is a single value, not an array. How could it be?

Comment: You have your return statement in the loop, so it will return during the first iteration and never do any more.  What do you expect that to produce?  Is that computation supposed to return an element?  A row?  Did you intend to gather up all the elements in a list before returning?

Comment: I need function U to return a sum over all odd indices for a given pair of arguments (y,z).

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are returning the first computed value since the `return` statement is inside the `for loop`.

To fix it, store the computed values in a list and then return the list.

```
def U(y,z):
    array = []
    for j in range (1,21,2):
        array.append(a*np.sum(((-1)**(0.5*(j-1)))*(1-cosh(j,z)/cosh(j,h/2))*np.cos(j*pi*y/w)/j**3))
    return array
```